# Flask-SQLAlchemy with_for_update() row lock

Tags: python, mysql, flask, locking, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a model called 'User', and 'User' has 'Money'.
There a scenario that multiple session can read the model 'User' and update 'money' at the same time.

Session 2 should read the 'money' value after session 1 updated successfully.
I tried to lock the 'User' row when updating.
Here's my code.

```
user = User.query.with_for_update().filter_by(id=userid).first()
print('000000')
before_money = user.money
print('111111')
time.sleep(1)
user.money -= 0.1
print('User:' + str(user.id) + '***' + str(before_money) + '-' + str(0.1) + ' = ' + str(user.money))
time.sleep(1)
db.session.commit()
print('22222')
```

I opened two session to run this code at the same time, the output

```
000000
111111
User:1***125.3-0.1 = 125.2
000000
111111
22222
User:1***125.3-0.1 = 125.2
22222
```

Session 2 didn't read the updated value.

I would really like to know where the problem is.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

After struggling for one whole day, i found the problem.

```
user = User.query.with_for_update().filter_by(id=userid).first()
```

should be

```
result = db.session.query(User.money).with_for_update().filter_by(id=userid).first()
money = result[0]
user.money = money - 0.1
```

Yes, so simple but annoying

Comment: not "anoying", just "logical" : query is a function, would feel weird to ask a "for update" on it... It makes much more sense to do it on the **result** (the actual query). Note that I think you can add it after the filter too (since these functions return queries

Comment: @hl037_I think he should add them after the filter since he's locking the whole table doing it like this (at least I think so)

Comment: @juan That doesn't make a difference according to my test.

Comment: from where are you getting 'user' in user.money = money - 0.1

Comment: For anyone looking to ensure atomic row updates, this is the solution that worked for me

Answer (score 7):

You just need to state what you want to lock:

```
user = User.query.with_for_update(of=User).filter_by(id=userid).first()
user.money -= 0.1
```