# SqlAlchmey add new row to table based on other rows values

Tags: python, sql, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

In the following code, I'm trying to add a new row to `TransferRequest` table if there is a row in the table that:

1-  the value of `partnerId` column is the same as what I expect

2- and the status of this row is now `open`

and after inserting I want to change the status of the filtered row to the `booked`

```
        partner = db.session.query(TransferRequest).filter(TransferRequest.id == partner_id).one()
        if partner.status == RequestStatus.open.value:
            request = TransferRequest()
            #set values

            db.session.add(request)
            db.session.commit()

            db.session.query(TransferRequest). \
                filter(TransferRequest.id == partner_id). \
                update({"status": RequestStatus.booked.value,
                        "partnerId": request.id})
            db.session.commit()

            return "success"
        else:
            return "failure"
```

The problem here is that when I query for the item with specific id and check its status, after reaching the `if` condition it is possible that someone else changes the status of the row from `open` to `booked`. In this case, I must not insert the row and must not do the `update` command after the insertion.

I'm looking for a way that I can do all of these 3 queries in a transaction so that all the data situation lock from the first statement to the end statement. (or of-course any other solutions that can fix the problem)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the main problem in your code is using commit() twice. Which commits everything to the database (as a transaction) and then releases underlying transaction locks. The second thing is, I should also add with_for_update() to your select query, to lock specific rows. Finish off with a one-time commit to persist your changes and release locks. An example could be:

```
    session = sessionmaker(bind=engine, autocommit=False)

    partner = session.query(TransferRequest).with_for_update().filter(TransferRequest.id == partner_id).one()
    if partner.status == RequestStatus.open.value:
        request = TransferRequest()
        #set values

        session.add(request)
        session.flush()

        session.query(TransferRequest). \
            filter(TransferRequest.id == partner_id). \
            update({"status": RequestStatus.booked.value,
                    "partnerId": request.id})
        session.commit()

        return "success"
    else:
        return "failure"
```

Comment: does only committing one time causes that my first query to the 'TransferRequest' locks the row and doesn't allow someone else changes the status of the filtered row? Because I'm worried that after filtering, between the code for setting the values, adding them to the table and updating the filtered row another request execute sooner and book the row before I book it. I want to avoid this.

Comment: For this exact behaviour, I added with_for_update(), this should be what you need to place a lock on the rows during the select. More info about the method here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40700309/flask-sqlalchemy-with-for-update-row-lock

Comment: the problem is that if I remove the first commit, `request.id` that is used to update the filtered row has not any values because the `id` is and `autoincrement` field

Comment: You could probably use flush() instead of your first commit()